# Oracle's Bitmap Index in SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, indexing, performance, physical-design

I've been successfully using bitmap indexes for years in Oracle environment. Now I'm working on a data warehouse project which will be hosted on SQL Server 2005. So far, I was unable to find an answer for bitmap like indexes in SQL Server.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not really a direct equivalent.  However, SQL Server has something called bitmap filtering. You can read about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522541.aspx

Unfortunately, this feature seems to have been introduced in SQL Server 2008, so it probably won't help you much since you are using SQL Server 2005.